# Android Google Map filled circle

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying to make a map overlay that just shows a solid circle from the map center who's radius is a range in meters.

I can't figure out how to calculate the circle's radius. I can get the map center, but I haven't had any luck figuring out how to convert meters into the proper units for the circle's radius.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check out this library, it may help: https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas

Answer (score 1):

I've got no experience of doing this in a gMaps context, but [the MapView class](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html) (whose `getProjection()` I'm assuming you've used to work out where your point is on the screen) has `getLatitudeSpan()` and `getLongitudeSpan()` which you can use against the screen res to calculate the pixel-radius of your circle.

Comment: i figured it out but can't answer my own questions but thanks.